# Image from local uri (file:///[...]/cache/[...].jpg) not showing after app reload

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo and ImagePicker to select pictures from camera roll in a react native app, and showing it in component.

```
<Image key={i} source={{ isStatic: true, uri: this.state.pictures[0].uri }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, resizeMode: "cover"}}/>
```

works just fine when I chose the picture from `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync[..]`. State is updated, the picture is shown in `<Image />` etc.

The uri is `file:///[...]/cache/[...]`

But when I reload the app later with expo, the picture is not shown. The uri is stored in redux store, etc.

I logged the uri and it works fine, the right uri is returned. READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are added.

What am I missing ? Do I have to store the picture somewhere else when I pick it so it's not in cache directory ?

Comment: when you run the url on phone browser, can u show the image after reloaded? Because your chache image deleted after reloaded. You can be sure about that.

Comment: That's the problem @YasinUgurlu

Comment: I'm looking for a way to move it to a permanent folder when it is picked, so it's reachable at next app init

Comment: okey dont use the 'file://' from path. just use the path without 'file://'

Comment: Tried, without file://, without file:///, nothing. Begninning to think this is a permission problem

Comment: I have had this same issue and couldn't get uri based images to work, but passing the image object into source worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue - turns out it was working, but the image needed a height setting.

Comment: Accordinge to OP's code, there is a height setting. Is there anything else missing?